# How to see regression F-test as comparison of sample variances?

Tags: regression, anova, f-test

F-test is designed for [comparison of variances of two samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances). In one-way ANOVA, [it can be simply interpreted like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Multiple-comparison_ANOVA_problems):

$$F = {\text{explained variance} \over \text{unexplained variance}}$$

I was thus expecting, that F-test for linear regression* it will be the same - testing explained variance vs unexplained. However, [the expression is different](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/csc423/documents/f-test-reg.htm):

$$F = {{\text{SSReg} \over {p - 1}}\over{\text{SSR} \over {N - p}}}$$

where $p$ is number of regression parameters (including intercept), and N is data size; SSReg is regression sum of squares, SSR is residual sum of squares (definitions e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares#Partitioning_in_the_general_ordinary_least_squares_model)). I was trying to understand where does this come from, and I found that it is a special case of [using F-test to compare two models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems), where the first one is a NULL model (with intercept only).

But, **(The Question) how can be the above expression interpreted in the sense of comparing sample variances?** I don't see it, because for simple regression with one slope $p - 1 = 1$, so the numerator of the fraction is a sum of squares of regression predictions of $N$ data records divided by one, this can hardly be interpreted as variance? Or? I guess there must be some way how to interpret this back to the notion of comparing variances, because that is the base of the F-test.

---

*) the F-test for linear regression as performed e.g. in R in `summary(lm(..))` or `anova(lm(...))` commands.

Comment: Briefly, you're comparing the variance of the residuals of your model to the variance of the residuals of a simpler model, and this is why we use a test for variances.

Comment: @Dave, no, not really. The sample variance is a sum of squares divided by $N - 1$. These aren't.